# counting tags and outputing variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>

<script>



$(document).ready(function () { 

var items = document.getElementByTag('section').length;

alert(items);       

 });



</script>
</head>
       <body>
       <section>
 This should be counted
 </section>
 <section>
 This should be counted
 </section>
 <section>
 This should be counted
    </section>
     <section>
     This should be counted
     </section>
     <section>
     This should be counted
     </section>

  There are currently <b id='test'></b> alerts


</body>
```

I want to be able to count the number of section elements in my code when the page is loaded. I want it to be inserting it where     `<b>` is. However I cannot get it to count the elements. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would seem you haven't fully grasped the basics yet, so have a read of a [basic introduction to jQuery tutorial](http://andreehansson.se/the-basics-of-jquery/) to try and understand the foundations of the framework.

Comment: try this `var items = $('section').length;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't include jQuery library in your page to make the following work:

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

Next, if you think of using pure JavaScript, then you should consider that there is no method `getElementByTag`, there is a method [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) (follow `s` after `Element`).

So finally, you have to either include jQuery in the page and use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').text($('section').length);
});
```

or put your `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag and write something like:

```
var sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section'),
    text = document.createTextNode(sections.length);

document.getElementById('test').appendChild(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery selector for that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#test").html($("section").length());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what VisioN meant to say was

"First of all, you **didn't** include the jQuery library in your page [which is required] to  make the following work:"

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ct = document.querySelectorAll('section').length;

document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = ct;
```